# Как получить данные из моего laravel проекта в отдельный vue.js проект?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Как я могу получить данные со своего laravel проекта в отдельном vue.js проекте? Пытался найти информацию в гугле, но везде нахожу не совсем то что мне нужно. То есть я понимаю, что я должен из vue.js проекта отправлять запросы на сервер с помощью axios. Вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать на стороне laravel? Нужно ли писать api и вообще какие способы существуют?

Answer (score 0):

На стороне Laravel вам необходимо создать API, через который вы будете извлекать данные с помощью axios из Vue.

Неплохая статья по созданию API на Laravel: https://www.twilio.com/blog/building-and-consuming-a-restful-api-in-laravel-php